# Bash inaccessible return code

Tags: bash

Consider the following code fragment inside a function:

```
local -r LSBLK_FAILED="Lsblk failed"
for f in $(lsblk -lno MOUNTPOINT "$DEVPATH"); do
    sudo umount "$f";
    RET=$?
    if (( $RET != 0 )); then
        echo "Unable to dismount $f - error $UNABLE_DISMOUNT_PARTITION"
        return $UNABLE_DISMOUNT_PARTITION
    fi
done
if [[ "$f" -eq "$LSBLK_FAILED" ]]; then
    echo "Problem running Lsblk"
fi
```

The problem I have is that I cannot see how to access the return code for the **lsblk** command. I can detect whether the command failed but I cannot access the actual return code. Can anyone suggest how I might do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the call to `lsblk` into a separate command. Then you can get its exit status from `$?`.

```
l=$(lsblk -lno MOUNTPOINT "$DEVPATH")
if (( !$? )); then
  for f in $l; do
    // etc.
```

Actually it seems like you can use a conditional with the assignment as well:

```
if l=$(lsblk...); then
```